# I can't edit a drupal module, the css location is incredibly difficult to find

Tags: css, drupal

I need to edit a css file that manages the position of certain buttons for a block.

Using Google Chrome to inspect the element, Drupal only gives me this information about the css file name: DSFJHjdfkvwvSDFVSFbvnhsdjnvjsdnfjbvw.css

Wonderful... that doesn't exist. How am I suppose to pinpoint the exact location of a css file? I've torn apart the css files within the styles folder in themes.

So basically finding the source code for everything in drupal requires you to find the needle in the haystack. Is there a way to find exactly what css files my webpage is using by using the admin panel??

Answer (score 0):

Drupal, for performance reasons , aggregates all CSS files into one generated file so only 1 request Is needed to load all necessary styles.

You can disable this (not recommended on a prd site) by going to the performance settings in drupal config and disabling js and CSS optimizations.

Clear the cache and now you will see the specific file the CSS rule lives in when inspecting in chrome tools.

As a side note, it is not recommended to edit anything in a contributed module unless you contribute it back. Otherwise, when you need to upgrade to the next version of the module, you will lose your previous changes. I would just apply CSS rules in your custom theme that override the modules CSS.

Sorry if there are typos. This was written on my phone and I will clean it up when I am at my desk.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your drupal configuration you have enabled the "Aggregate and compress CSS files" settings. Try disabling it by going to Configuration > Development > Performance. It might solve you problem.

You can revert back the setting after you have made changes.

Answer (score -1):

Turn of the caching and  then clear the cache. You should then get the correct location of the CSS rules. Once you are done with this, enable caching again.

Comment: Ridiculous! Any Drupal dev have learned by just mentioning the cache!